# Difference between gettextf and sprintf

Tags: r, printf

I have read [the documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) for `gettextf` and `sprintf`.  The two appear to give the same results:

```
sprintf("%f", pi) == gettextf("%f", pi)
sprintf("%.3f", pi) == gettextf("%.3f", pi)
sprintf("%1.0f", pi) == gettextf("%1.0f", pi)
sprintf("%5.1f", pi) == gettextf("%5.1f", pi)
sprintf("%G", 1e-6 * pi) == gettextf("%G", 1e-6 * pi)
```

The documentation states:

> `sprintf` is a wrapper for the system sprintf C-library function. Attempts are made to check that the mode of the values passed match the format supplied, and R's special values (NA, Inf, -Inf and NaN) are handled correctly.
>
> `gettextf` is a convenience function which provides C-style string formatting with possible translation of the format string.

I am trying to understand what the actual differences between the two functions are in terms a former first grade teacher can understand.

<s>My understanding is that `sprintf` actually uses the system function where as `gettextf` mimics the formating.  Is `gettextf` portable across platforms?</s>

**Edit**

The source for `gettextf` indicates it uses `sprintf`

```
> gettextf
function (fmt, ..., domain = NULL) 
sprintf(gettext(fmt, domain = domain), ...)
<bytecode: 0x0706831c>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They key to understanding what `gettextf()` might be useful for is to follow the link to [gettext](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/gettext.html).

These are the output functions used for what is commonly called *i18n* or internationalization, ie when you want to automagically have your (error) message display a translated version provided by someone you don't even know.

The system sees that you want to print "foo not a match for bar" and some other folks can then provide translated messages for non-English use. At display time, the match is looked up in the po files and a suitable translated message is displayed where available.  Such behaviour is common in R itself, but somewhat rare in CRAN package which generally do not have po files.

Comment: Thanks Dirk.  Makes sense now.